# Haskell list comprehension 0's and 1's

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to write a function

```
row :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
row n v
```

that returns a list of `n` integers, all `0`'s, except for the `v`th element, which needs to be a `1`.

For instance,

```
row 0 0 = []
row 5 1 = [1,0,0,0,0]
row 5 3 = [0,0,1,0,0]
```

I am new to Haskell and having a lot of difficulty with this. In particular I can't figure out how to make it repeat `0`'s. I understand the concept of building a list from let's say `[1..n]`, but I just get `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Shabu. If you feel your question has been answered, please select one of the answers as the accepted answer. That way, others can quickly find a solution that works for your problem, without going through all answers. You select an answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the question.

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
let row n v = map (\x -> if x == v then 1 else 0) [1..n]
```

Comment: Even shorter: `row n v = map (fromEnum.(== v)) [1..n]`

Comment: @Landei: shorter, but obfuscates the meaning a bit.

Answer (score 11):

Here a "monadic" solution:

```
row n v = [(v-1, 0), (1, 1), (n-v, 0)] >>= (uncurry replicate)
```

The `replicate` function repeats a given value a number of times, e.g. `replicate (v-1) 0` gives a list of `v-1` zeros. The `uncurry` is used to modify the `replicate` in order to accept a tuple instead of two single arguments. The funny operator `>>=` is the heart of a monad; for lists it is the same as `concatMap` with flipped arguments.

Comment: This is perhaps the best solution, as it's extremely easy to generalize.

Comment: Probably the cleverest indeed, but not necessarilly the easiest to read

Comment: I just started out with a solution like the one from Ankur, but the repetition of `replicate` bugged me.

Comment: This "solution" gives [1] for row 0 0 where it should evaluate to [].

Answer (score 8):

With a comprehensive list :

```
 row n v = [if x == v then 1 else 0 | x <- [1..n]]
```

Or using `fromEnum` (thanks dave4420)

```
 row n v = [fromEnum (x == v) | x <- [1..n]]
```

Comment: That shortest way is `fromEnum`.

Answer (score 3):

This should also work:

```
row n v = replicate (v-1)­ 0 ++ [1] ++ repl­icate (n-v)­ 0
```

Answer (score 1):

And yet another solution, recursively building up the list:

```
row :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
row 0 _ = []
row n 1 = 1 : (row (n-1) 0)
row n m = 0 : (row (n-1) (m-1))
```

And a more readable one, where zeros are "taken":

```
row :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
row 0 _ = []
row n m = take (m - 1) zeros ++ [1] ++ take (n - m) zeros
    where zeros = (iterate id 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive loop with two temporary variables  c and lst . c is for counting and lst is list which we have to return.

```
row :: Int -> Int -> [ Int ]
row 0 0 = []
row n v = rowHelp n v 1 [] where
    rowHelp n v c lst
            | c > n = lst
            | v == c = rowHelp n v ( c + 1 ) ( lst ++ [ 1 ] )
            | otherwise = rowHelp n v ( c + 1 ) ( lst ++ [ 0 ] )
```

~
~

Answer (score 0):

the fun with haskell is that it let's you write your program very much the way you would express the algorithm. So try:

```
row n v = [if (x `mod` v==0) then 1 else 0  | x <- [1..n] ]
```

At first you create a list from 1,2 to n.
Then you check if the number is divisible by v, if it is, 1 is inserted in the output list, if not 0.

Examples:

```
> row 0 0
[]
> row 5 1
[1,0,0,0,0]
> row 5 3
[0,0,1,0,0]
> row 15 3
[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
```

HTH Chris

Comment: Seems the `mod` part is your invention, I don't see any *each* or *every* in the question. And at least your second example is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I like to demonstrate a top down approach, based on Chris's solution:

```
row n v = result           
    where
        result = take n numbers        -- our result will have a length of n
        numbers = map trans [1,2,..]   -- and is some transformation of
                                       -- the list of natural numbers
        trans e
           | e `mod` v == 0  = 1       -- let every v-th element be 1
           | otherwise       = 0       -- 0 otherwise
```

This style emphasizes the idea in functional programming that one writes down what a certain value like `row n v` *is supposed to be*, rather than trying to write down what *a function does*. In reminiscence of a well known joke about the lesser known pragramming language Sartre one could say that in pure functional programming functions *do* nothing, they just *are*.

Comment: create an infinite list, and taking the beginning of it seems a bit procedural for me. You write 2 statements , which both do something (computing the infinite list and then take the beginning). This is not at all (IMO) writing how things are supposed to be, but more how to do it, which is what you say which should not do . map trans [1..n] seems easies to read, isn't it ?

Comment: I am sorry you don't like it and I did not say it's the most efficient or shortest source code way.